# What is the mathematical motivation behind the "Second Fundamental Form" and How is it related to Gaussian Curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry

I understand the first fundamental form but couldn't understand the second fundamental form and How these two are related to Gaussian Curvature. Could you explain?

Comment: Your question is rather vague. Presumably you've looked over the definition of the second fundamental form? And thought about its meaning? If so, your post would be greatly improved if you could formulate a specific mathematical question regarding where you got stuck in this process.

Comment: Have you read any standard differential geometry textbooks? Perhaps you could peruse some and get some answers, and then come and ask us a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADDED: Since Ted didn't completely like my answer, I thought I'd provide another way to explain the second fundamental form. If you have a surface in $3$-space, you can move it around by rotations and translations without changing its shape. So, given any point on the surface, you can move the surface so that the point is at the origin and the tangent plane at that point is the $xy$-plane. The surface near the origin is now a graph of a function,
$$ z= f(x,y), $$
where $f(0,0) = 0$ and the partial derivatives satisfy $f_x(0,0) = f_y(0,0) = 0$. In other words, the origin is a critical point of $f$. With the surface positioned like this, the second fundamental form at the origin is simply the Hessian of $f$ there,
$$
H = \begin{bmatrix} f_{xx} & f_{xy} \\ f_{yx} & f_{yy} \end{bmatrix}
$$
As you know, eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $H$ tell you something about the shape of the surface near that point. So that's what the second fundamental form tells you about the shape of the surface near any given point on it.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:
Here's the short version: The second fundamental form, as you must know, encodes the directional derivative of the unit normal vector, as a function of the point on the surface. If the surface is flat, the unit normal is constant and therefore the derivative is zero in every direction. Otherwise, the second fundamental form tell you how curved the surface is, if you head in a given direction. Since the second fundamental form turns out to be represented as a symmetric matrix, there is a direction with minimal curvature and an orthogonal direction with maximal curvature. The Gauss curvature is simply the product of these so-called principal curvatures, which is also the determinant of the second fundamental form written as a matrix with respect to an orthonormal frame.

This explanation is not enough to really understand what's going on. You achieve that only by studying the details carefully, say from @TedShifrin's book and doing all the calculations yourself. It might not make sense at first, but if you persist, it eventually will.

Comment: This is a bit misleading, as you're purposely confusing the second fundamental form with the Weingarten map or shape operator.